# python matplotlib image - invert white & black as default

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm starting to play with openCV & am working through the Programming Computer Vision with Python book. It seems like I have a default that's set as the inverse (or reverse?) of what the book is using because where the image is black on my computer, the image is white in the book.

Is there any way to set the default to flip the white & black without doing a calculation each time?

Here's some sample code from the book. In the book, the background is white, but on my computer, it is black:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
from scipy.ndimage import filters

im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg').convert('L'))

sigma = 5
imx = zeros(im.shape)
filters.gaussian_filter(im,(sigma,sigma),(0,1),imx)  
imy = zeros(im.shape)
filters.gaussian_filter(im,(sigma,sigma),(1,0),imy)  
magnitude = sqrt(imx**2+imy**2)  

figure()  
subplot(1,4,1)
imshow(im)
subplot(1,4,2)
imshow(imx)
subplot(1,4,3)
imshow(imy)
subplot(1,4,4)
imshow(magnitude)
```

I'm on a mac book pro & using python 2.7. This has probably been answered somewhere, but I couldn't find an answer - probably not using the right tags/keywords... thx in advance.

Comment: use the `gray_r` color map.  Tad surprised it is not coming up as jet (sadly the) default color mop....

Comment: thanks, but if there is such a thing as a default color map, is there a way to change the background such that the background is one color (white) and everything else is another (either colors or shades of gray?)

Comment: @tacaswell, you should post a proper answer with `gray_r` as your solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's not default, but you can invert the colors by subtract the array from 1:

`plt.imshow(1 - array)`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @tacaswell in the comments of OP's question, you may use the color map `gray_r` in matplotlib pyplot's imshow method for having a reverse gray plot. Alternatively, you may use color maps `binary` and `gist_yarg` (as shown in [matplotlib's documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html#sequential2)). Just a curiosity: notice the pun in the term "gist_yarg": "yarg" is "gray" written in the reverse order.

As an illustrative example, to plot OP's image `im` with reverse gray colormap, one could do:

```py
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = array(Image.open('empire.jpg').convert('L'))

plt.imshow(X=im, cmap="gray_r")
```